# Viewing log messages with Emacs

Tags: python, logging, emacs, log-viewer

After running the Python code

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='./output.log',
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format=('%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s --'
                            ' %(processName)s '
                            '%(filename)s:%(lineno)s -- '
                            '%(message)s'))
logging.debug('This is a debug message')
logging.info('This is an info message')
logging.warning('This is a warning message')
logging.error('This is an error message')
logging.critical('This is a critical message')
```

I get in the log file **output.log** the following content.

```
2019-09-04 14:24:32,268 DEBUG -- MainProcess experiment.py:9 -- This is a debug message
2019-09-04 14:24:32,268 INFO -- MainProcess experiment.py:10 -- This is an info message
2019-09-04 14:24:32,268 WARNING -- MainProcess experiment.py:11 -- This is a warning message
2019-09-04 14:24:32,269 ERROR -- MainProcess experiment.py:12 -- This is an error message
2019-09-04 14:24:32,269 CRITICAL -- MainProcess experiment.py:13 -- This is a critical message
```

When I read the file with Emacs 26.2 started using the following `~/.emacs`

```
(set-foreground-color "white")
(set-background-color "black")
(global-font-lock-mode t)
(setq font-lock-maximum-decoration t)
(require 'logview)
```

I end up with a tedious monochromatic image

[image: logging output is monochromatic]

which makes it hard to scan for errors/warnings, and to scan the elements of each log message.

I understand that there is no such a thing as a standard ".log" format, or at least multiple formats competing for the `.log` extension. Still, can you suggest some elisp package along with perhaps a specific extension that will distinguish through font-lock the log levels as well as the elements of each log message?

Comment: Did you *use* `logview-mode` in that buffer?

Comment: @DavisHerring Good point. The mode is set to `logview-mode` alright, but there is a prequel https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/46123/3922 that needs solving.